# how to display custom text in data bound GridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I am working on RadGridView of telerik. I have a "GridViewComboBoxColumn" with a list of strings as data source.

Now the problem is that when I populate the grid view with data, it is possible that the value in data is not available in the strings data source for that column which results in blank value.

I tried setting DropDownStyle to RadDropDownStyle.DropDown but that doesn't change anything. And I just need to display the data even if that is not present in the drop down list.

Here is some code to help you understand it better.

```
    Dim lstValues As New List(Of String)
    lstValues.Add("Approved")
    lstValues.Add("Declined")
    lstValues.Add("Pending")

    Dim col5 As GridViewComboBoxColumn = RadGridView1.Columns("column2")
    col5.DataSource = lstValues
    col5.DropDownStyle = Telerik.WinControls.RadDropDownStyle.DropDown
```

Now the row being added would be following.

```
    RadGridView1.Rows.Add("Application Name", "Processing")
```

As you can see that column2 has no item named "Processing" so it is not displayed and showing as blank.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [formatting events](http://More%20information%20about%20the%20formatting%20events%20can%20be%20found%20here:%C2%A0http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-formatting-cells.html) and set the cell text to whatever you need, however, note that the cell value will not be changed by this, but this is what you need as far as I can understand.

```
 void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "column2" && e.Row.Cells["someColumn"].Value == something)
        {
            e.CellElement.Text = "some text";
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.TextProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to have resolved the problem. However, one question though, why do we need "e.CellElement.ResetValue" here?

Comment: The article explains it. The grid uses UI virtualization and cells are being reused. So, to avoid your modifications to be applied on unwanted cells, you need this reset.
If this answers your question, please mark my post as answer.